# RST Sphinx - add hyperlink to internal image

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

How to add hyperlink to INTERNAL image in RST for sphinx?
I want to have something like it:

```
Examples: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

and then when i click on 1 i want it to move to imgs/1.png etc.
I was trying to use `::image: imgs/1.png` but that just renders picture and then when i am trying to:

```
Examples: 1_
:: _1: ../_images/1.png
```

it doesn't copy the picture, so how do i combine them both? so i got a copied image that i can use as a hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to click `1`, and the web browser jumps to the referenced image.

First set up the targets using the [`name`](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#name) attribute.

```
.. image:: ../_images/1.png
    :name: 1

.. image:: ../_images/2.png
    :name: 2
```

Then reference the targets.

```
Examples: `1`_, `2`_
```